# programmatically create container view in ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

I know how to create a container view in iOS via storyboard but it won't let me have a container view in a collection view cell. I'd like one of the cells to load another controller as a container. How would I go about doing this?

Comment: Hey popeye, mainly, when you try dragging a container view in a storyboard to a collection view cell the compiler says you can't use a re-usable cell with a container

Comment: How does that relate to what I just asked?

Answer (score 10):

Before I give you the code you must realize this is certainly a bad idea. `UITableViewCells` are highly reusable and are just raw views not backed by a a real view controller (just a data source). Container views are designed to be nested controllers and not just placed inside of a `UIView` (like a table cell). But I digress:

Here is the Apple docs related to [container views](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIViewController_Class/index.html) (search for *container view*).

Under the section *Adding and Removing a Child*:

```
// Adding a container view
[self addChildViewController:content];                 // 1
content.view.frame = [self frameForContentController]; // 2
[self.view addSubview:content.view];
[content didMoveToParentViewController:self];          // 3
```

```
// Removing a container view
[content willMoveToParentViewController:nil];  // 1
[content.view removeFromSuperview];            // 2
[content removeFromParentViewController];      // 3
```

When configuring a cell it will most likely already have a container view inside of it (from its previous configuration). So before adding a new one on top of that you should first attempt to reuse what you have already added. But again, this solution is not really advisable, but you already should know that since IB blocked you from doing it.

Comment: So currently using a collection view, would I be better off just doing a uiscroll view with the individual sections done a tad more manually (and static instead of re-usable)? I figure in that case I could just use the container view from the storyboard

Comment: @moger777, yes that would be a great substitute solution. You definitely could do that in storyboard too, but I will say that doing it in code will be much more versatile. Like if you want to switch two of the 'sections' or add a new one between two current ones. Doing that in storyboard will require lots of constraint updates. Doing it in code will probably just require adding a new element to an array (that is looped over in code to add all of the container views in subsequent order).

Comment: I'm a bit confused on what currentClientView is supposed to be here

Comment: This is just copied from the Apple docs. It would be the vc's view. I updated the answer to be more appropriate to the code samples (`content.view`).

Comment: @SilviuSt I updated the link, unfortunately I could not find as good of a doc reference, but is still pretty good. My answer contains all the appropriate information though anyway, so the doc is just for extra reference. Thanks for pointing that out though!